# Why is the output different for following part of code?

Tags: python, list

The output for G and G1 list is different.

```
numCourses = 2
prerequisites = [[1,0]]

G = [[] for i in range(numCourses)]

G1 = [[]]*numCourses

for i,j in prerequisites:
    G[j].append(i)

for i,j in prerequisites:
    G1[j].append(i)
```

I get following output `G = [[1],[]]` and `G1 = [[1],[1]]`

Comment: Please also read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

It's a classic python gotcha

```
G = [[] for i in range(numCourses)]
```

creates `numCourses` new, empty list, while

```
G1 = [[]]*numCourses
```

first creates the (inner) empty list, and then a list consisting of `numCourses` copies of it. That's why when you change one list in `G1` all of them change.